# android TV select item of BrowseSupportFragment/RowsSupportFragment programmatically by index

Tags: java, android, television

I want to set selected view by index inside the row I'm in. Logically it might be something like this:

```
getRowsSupportFragment().getRowViewHolder(rowIndex).setSelectedPosition(viewIndex);
```

Well there is not anything like `setSelectedPosition` in the list of function of `getRowViewHolder(0)`
 I have managed to change selected row by index with this line : `getRowsSupportFragment().setSelectedPosition(index);`
But I want to change selected View inside the row..

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 3):

To select a specific item in a row you simply call `setSelectedPosition()`.

In Java:

```
setSelectedPosition(rowindex, true, new ListRowPresenter.SelectItemViewHolderTask(channelIndex));
```

In Kotlin:

```
setSelectedPosition(rowindex, true, SelectItemViewHolderTask(channelIndex))
```

CJ!

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin equivalent

```
setSelectedPosition(rowIndex, true, object : ListRowPresenter.SelectItemViewHolderTask(itemIndex){
            override fun run(holder: Presenter.ViewHolder?) {
                val itemView = holder?.view
                //do whatever you want
            }
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    val rowViewHolder = getRowViewHolder(rowIndex)
    val horizontalGridView = (rowViewHolder as ListRowPresenter.ViewHolder).gridView
    horizontalGridView.setSelectedPosition(cardPos)
```

Above can be used to select required card in required row and if still focus is not handled adding below code helps.

```
   horizontalGridView.getChildAt(cardPos).requestFocus()
```